# Problems saving frontend client value with MERN stack to backend server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, redux

I am having a problem with saving a value from the client to backend server, what it's suppose to do is on button click essentially save the previous value and increase it by one

VoteReducer

```
import {
    FETCH_SERVERID,
    FETCH_VOTE,
    UPDATE_VOTE,
    INCREASE_VOTE
} from './constants';

const initialState = {
    serverID: '',
    voteCount: '',
};

const voteReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_SERVERID:
            return {
                ...state,
                serverID: action.payload
            };
        case FETCH_VOTE:
            return {
                ...state,
                fetchVote: action.payload
            };
        case UPDATE_VOTE:
            return {
                ...state,
                voteCount: {
                    ...state.voteCount, ...action.payload,
                }
            }
        case INCREASE_VOTE:
            return state + 1
        default:
            return state;
    };
};

export default voteReducer;
```

Vote Actions

```
import { push } from 'connected-react-router';
import axios from 'axios';
import { success } from 'react-notification-system-redux';

import {
    FETCH_SERVERID,
    FETCH_VOTE,
    UPDATE_VOTE,
    INCREASE_VOTE
} from './constants';
import handleError from "../../utils/error";

export const fetchServerID = value => {
    return {
        type: FETCH_SERVERID,
        payload: value
    };
};

export const fetchVote = value => {
    return {
        type: FETCH_VOTE,
        payload: value
    };
};

export const increaseVote = () => {
    return {
        type: INCREASE_VOTE,
    };
};

    export const voteCount = vote => {
        return async (dispatch, getState) => {
            try {
    
                const voteValues = {
                    serverID: "",
                    voteCount: + 1
                }
                const voteCount = localStorage.getItem('vote_button')
    
                const newVote = {
                  votedServer: voteValues.serverID,
                  voteCount: voteValues.voteCount,
                };
    
                const successOptions = {
                    title: "Your vote has been succesfully recorded",
                    position: 'tr',
                    autodismiss: 1
                };
    
                const increasingVote = {
                    title: "We are increasing your vote count test ",
                    position: 'tr',
                    autodismis: 1
                };
                dispatch(success(increaseVote));
    
                const response = await axios.post('/api/vote/add', newVote);
                if(response.data.success === true) {
                    dispatch(success(successOptions));
                } else {
                    const retryOptions = {
                        title: "Please properly vote on a server",
                        position: 'tr',
                        autodismiss: 1
                    };
                    dispatch(warning(retryOptions));
                }
    
            } catch (error) {
                handleError(error, dispatch);
            }
        }
    }
```

Server side code

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Models/helpers

const Vote = require('../../models/vote');



router.post('/add', async (req, res) => {
    const serverID = req.body.serverID;
    const voteCount = req.body.voteCount;

    const vote = new Vote({
        serverID,
        voteCount,
    });

    const voteSave = await vote.save();

    await vote.save(async (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: 'Your request could not be completed at this time'
            });
        }

        res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            message: 'We are now counting your vote!',
            vote: voteSave
        });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Vote Index

```
class Vote extends React.PureComponent {

    render() {
        const {
            user,
            vote,
            voteCount,
        } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className='vote-page'>
             
                <button
                variant='primary'
                text='Vote'
                className='vote_button'
                onClick={() => { voteCount(vote) }}>
                >Vote</button>
            </div>
       );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        user: state.account.user,
        voteCount: state.voteCount,
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Vote);
```

I literally started learning full stack development this week, uhm just trying to grasp advanced concepts but essentially what I want it to do is keep track of votes then increase it by one when a button is pressed/vote on from the client then passed to the server saved but increased by one every-time a user presses a vote on a specific page but I haven't got to the point of getting that to work nor have I gotten to the point of implementing a way for each type of listing to be different from one another when voted on

Hopefully someone answers soon! Thanks

Comment: Is it should be `req.body.votedServer` instead of `req.body.serverID` ?

Comment: I don't think that's in the body of the page I can edit my question with the index code

Comment: It posts it correctly that's the thing I just can't seem to get it to count up by one when posted (incremented) then get it to save that document instead of producing multiple it should simply update a single document with an ID then when clicked increment that by one but I am having trouble understanding on how to do that